# Regex to work on XML tags - Help needed

Tags: regex, xml

I have some pseudo-XML which I'm trying to clean up, and I'm most of the way there, but there's a problem with casing in tags.

My source looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <float_node>1.0</float_node>
  <text_node>Pack My Box</text_node>
  <UPPER_NODE>With Five Dozen</UPPER_NODE>
  <MiXeD_NoDe>SCSG1</MiXeD_NoDe>
  <!-- Comment should not be changed -->
  <GRANDPARENT>
    <PARENT>
      <Child1>Liquor Jugs</Child1>
      <Child2 with-attribute="Pangrams">Jackdaws Love</Child2>
    </PARENT>
    <PARENT>
      <Child1>My Big Sphinx</Child1>
      <Child2 with-attribute="Are Great">Of Gold</Child2>
    </PARENT>
  </GRANDPARENT>
</root>
```

but what I want is this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <float_node>1.0</float_node>
  <text_node>Pack My Box</text_node>
  <upper_node>With Five Dozen</upper_node>
  <mixed_node>SCSG1</mixed_node>
  <!-- Comment should not be changed -->
  <grandparent>
    <parent>
      <child1>Liquor Jugs</child1>
      <child2 with-attribute="Pangrams">Jackdaws Love</child2>
    </parent>
    <parent>
      <child1>My Big Sphinx</child1>
      <child2 with-attribute="Are Great">Of Gold</child2>
    </parent>
  </grandparent>
</root>
```

So far I have this pattern...

```
<(.+)( .+)?>(.*)<\/\1>
```

and this substitution...

```
<\L$1$2>$3</\L$1>
```

but the output is wrong...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <float_node>1.0</float_node>
  <text_node>pack my box</text_node>
  <upper_node>with five dozen</upper_node>
  <mixed_node>scsg1</mixed_node>
  <data_format>excel</data_format>
  <!-- Comment should not be changed -->
  <GRANDPARENT>
    <PARENT>
      <child1>liquor jugs</child1>
      <child2 with-attribute="pangrams">jackdaws love</child2>
    </PARENT>
    <PARENT>
      <child1>my big sphinx</child1>
      <child2 with-attribute="are great">of gold</child2>
    </PARENT>
  </GRANDPARENT>
</root>
```

The \L lowercasing is being applied to the tag content and attribute as well as the tags, even though the substitution string has $2 and $3 distinct and unaltered.

Nested nodes are overlooked. Only the innermost node is altered. How should I manage the hierarchy?

Can anyone tell me where my pattern or substitution is failing?

I'm using Regex101 for help with building the regex pattern and testing... https://regex101.com/r/Oeshto/3

(I'm using Notepad++ to do the actual work since my preferred editor (VSCode) doesn't handle the required \L conversion.)

Comment: I don't see in what your example is "pseudo-XML", it seems to be well formed XML.

Comment: The example source posted is the "nearly there" stuff. The original source didn't have an XML header or root node, was littered with comments denoted by lines starting with "//", had elements containing strings with "<" and ">", and other factors, which I managed to resolve with simple Regex work.

Comment: It would have been interesting to post the original somewhere with all of these problems.

Comment: The original source contains sensitive data, so I could never post it unaltered. I had no problem with most of the fixes required, and just needed help with this tag casing issue. I created a minimal example to illustrate my start and desired end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the regular expressions to suit your needs. I'm sure some reg-ex wizard could optimise or make these better but they seem to get the job done. (Edited, I have removed my suggestion on the PEAR package as it was utterly nonsense when you asked for a regular-expression only)

```
Regular Expression.: /(<\/?[^!][^>]+)/g  ( Change all tags+attributes )
Regular Expression.: /(<\w+|<\/\w+)/g    ( Change only tags )
Substitution.......: \L$1
```

Don't forget the Global flag so it won't return after first result.
This should match all tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Pear uses PHP and, while I know enough to follow the examples, I don't have any tooling or skills to make good use of it. I'm just looking to run a one-time transform on a dozen or so files. I've used Regex in a text editor to alter each of them to resemble XML, and this is the final step to tidy up tag casing so that my parser doesn't treat <XYZ> and <xyz> as different entities.
Your Regex expression doesn't help - sorry.

Comment: @BrianLowe My regular expression is tested with your code and the substitution \L$1 - Does that not convert all tags and attributes to lower case and leave the rest ? I'm sorry if I missed something.

Comment: @BrianLowe I've added a second regular expression. This only changes the tags and don't touch the attributes. It's working as intended on regex101. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I was confused when I saw that your expression didn't provide the 3 separate groups I had expected, but you're simplifying it so that it's only acting with an opening or closing tag. Thanks!